# Выборка последнего значения из выборки для каждого члена выборки ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблицы st и LOG и dc.

Связаны по полю id_document - идентификатор документа в базе.
В st и dc значения id_document уникальны, в log - не уникальны.

Необходимо выводить:
поля из dc,
st.dateend,
последнюю строку из столбца log.desc, отсортированного по полю log.dateevent, для каждого значения id_document таблицы sendtitle,
log.dateevent строки log.desc.

Сейчас пришел только к запросу, выводящему все строки log.desc для каждого st.id_document, а как выбрать только последнюю строку не понятно.

Буду признателен за помощь.

```
SELECT
    dc.id_document,
    dc.comments,
    st.dateend,
    log.description,
    log.dateevent
FROM
    dc
    JOIN log ON log.id_document = dc.id_document
    JOIN st ON st .id_document = dc.id_document
WHERE
    dc.id_document in (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT st.id_document
        FROM
            st 
            INNER JOIN document          d ON d.id_document = st.id_document
        WHERE
            sysdate - d.timestamp > INTERVAL '4' HOUR
    )
order by log.dateevent desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      log.document_id,
      MAX(log.dateevent) AS dateevent
    FROM
      log
    GROUP BY
      log.document_id
  ) sub
  JOIN log ON (
    log.id_document = sub.id_document AND
    log.dateevent = sub.dateevent
  )
  JOIN dc ON sub.id_document = dc.id_document
  JOIN st ON st.id_document = dc.id_document
```

Список полей для выборки укажете самостоятельно.

Если пара (log.id_document, log.dateevent) не уникальна, то получите несколько записей

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5):

> а как выбрать только последнюю строку не понятно

Так и написать - *надо последнюю*, по ихнему [LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC):

```sql
select dc.*, st.dateend, log.description, log.dateevent
from dc
join st on st.id_document = dc.id_document
join (
    select id_document, 
    max (description) keep (dense_rank last order by dateevent asc) description,
    max (dateevent)   keep (dense_rank last order by dateevent asc) dateevent
    from log l
    group by l.id_document) log on log.id_document = st.id_document
order by dc.id_document
```

На [тестовых данных (см. fiddle)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=83b029341bd3d569c6b4a4c887d71cd6) ожидаю получить описание "description 3" от    03.07.
Так и есть:

```
ID_DOCUMENT COMMENTS  DATEEND             DESCRIPTION   DATEEVENT          
----------- --------- ------------------- ------------- -------------------
          1 comment 1 15.07.2021 00:00:00 description 3 03.07.2021 00:00:00
```